# conversion pine script v2 to v3 / v4

Tags: pine-script, indicator

This is the line that generates the v2 to v3 error
trendState = closeSeries > openSeries ? true : closeSeries < openSeries ? false : trendState[1]
line 40: Undeclared identifier `trendState`

if I cover the line in this way it is completed correctly but in v3 the indicator does not graphically correspond to version 2, it anticipates or postpones the trend change

trendState = false
trendState := closeSeries > openSeries ? true : closeSeries < openSeries ? false : trendState[1]

thanks for those who want to give me some welcome suggestions

Mark

Answer (score 1):

When transitioning from v2 to v3 self referencing variables need to be declared before hand. eg

```
bool trendState = na

trendState := closeSeries > openSeries ? true : closeSeries < openSeries ? false : trendState[1]
```